# Cannot get the text inside a <p> tag using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following URL

https://www.wavemotion.gr/shop/smartphone-accessories/easy-one-touch-wireless-fast-charging-mount

I am trying to get the availability of the product by using the following

```
For i = 2 To lastrow

mylink = wks.Cells(i, 2).Value

ie.Navigate mylink

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next

    Set instock = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.in-stock").innerText

    If instock Is Nothing Then
    Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.out-of-stock").innerText
    Else
    Set availability = instock
    End If

    wks.Cells(i, "D") = availability


    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop

Next i
```

But I get allways **nothing** on

```
Set instock = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.in-stock").innerText
```

I checked the query on

https://try.jsoup.org/

It is working

What I am doing wrong here? There is not any id to target only class name

```
<p class="stock in-stock">Διαθέσιμο</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what's happening here is that you're trying to `Set` string datatype `innerText` to object variable `instock`. The reason it's returning `Nothing` is because your `On Error Resume Next` statement is suppressing the error message. If you took that out and ran it, you would get a `Type Mismatch`. What you'd need to do is split it into a line that assigns the object to the object variable and then a line that reads the `innerText` of the assigned object.

```
Set instock = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.in-stock")

If instock Is Nothing Then
    Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.out-of-stock")
Else
    Set availability = instock
End If

wks.Cells(i, "D") = availability.innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better, faster way. Use xmlhttp and parse that info out of the json stored in one of the script tags. If issuing large numbers of requests you may need to add a wait every x number of requests in case of throttling/blocking. Note: You can use the same approach with InternetExplorer and thus remove many of your lines of code, though you have another library (.bas) dependancy.

You need to install jsonconverter.bas from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and go vbe > tools > references > and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetStocking()
    Dim json As Object, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.wavemotion.gr/shop/smartphone-accessories/easy-one-touch-wireless-fast-charging-mount", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(html.querySelector("script[type='application/ld+json']").innerHTML)

    Debug.Print json("offers")("availability")
End Sub
```

---

This is what the entire json contains:

[image]

---

**Internet Explorer version:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, s As String, scripts As Object, json As Object
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 "https://www.wavemotion.gr/shop/smartphone-accessories/easy-one-touch-wireless-fast-charging-mount"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set scripts = .document.querySelectorAll("script[type='application/ld+json']")

        For i = 0 To scripts.Length - 1
            s = scripts.item(i).innerHTML
            If InStr(s, "availability") > 0 Then
                Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
        If Not json Is Nothing Then Debug.Print json("offers")("availability")
    End With
End Sub
```