# Get data from URL using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to extract data from a [URL](https://www.justdial.com/Agartala/Abhay-Varieties-Nor-Banamalipu/9999PX381-X381-141028162716-U1Z5_BZDET).

I want data in an Excel column.

Title Name (Image 1 and 2)
Street Address
AddressLocality
postalcode
adressregion
addresscountry

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Here is my code.

```
url = Sheets("ExtData").Range("A" & N).Value
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With

Set html = New HTMLDocument
Dim titles As Object, addresses As Object, storesTextToDecipher As Object
With html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse

    Set titles = .querySelectorAll(".jcn [title]")
    Set addresses = .querySelectorAll(".desk-add.jaddt")

    Til = titles.Item(i).outerHTML
    Add = addresses.Item(i).innerText
    Sheets("ExtData").Range("B" & N) = .getElementsByClassName("Title").Item(0)
    Sheets("ExtData").Range("C" & N) = .getElementById("comp_add").outerHTML
    Range("A" & N + 1).Select
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a css class selector

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.justdial.com/Agartala/Abhay-Varieties-Nor-Banamalipu/9999PX381-X381-141028162716-U1Z5_BZDET", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print html.querySelector(".ph_hdr").innerText
End Sub
```

If you want separate lines then use

```
Dim items() As String, i As Long
items = Split(html.querySelector(".ph_hdr").innerText, ", ")
For i = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
    If items(i) <> vbNullString Then
        Activesheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = items(i)
    End If
Next
```

---

An odd situation is that normally I would [grab all the script tags with json using a css selector of  `script\[type='application/ld+json'\]` and loop that looking for the info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297196/6241235)<sub>1</sub>. However, despite the info being present when I look at a text file write out, the moment I use a DOM parser I cannot find that info. So, much as I hate to advocate regex with html, here is a regex solution:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, s As String, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.justdial.com/Agartala/Abhay-Varieties-Nor-Banamalipu/9999PX381-X381-141028162716-U1Z5_BZDET", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
        html.body.innerHTML = s
        Debug.Print html.querySelector(".fn").innerText
        Debug.Print Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "title>(.*)<"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        Debug.Print Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "streetAddress"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        Debug.Print Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressLocality"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        Debug.Print Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "postalCode"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        Debug.Print Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressRegion"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        Debug.Print Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressCountry"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            GetString = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    GetString = "No match"
End Function
```

1. I would use Instr looking for `"address":`

Comment: thanks Qharr Sir your solutions is perfect working ....

Debug.Print html.querySelector(".fn").innerText

there is one this I want for title is     Abhay Varieties,  but I want the full line of title its look like   "Abhay Varieties - Cosmetic Dealers in Agartala - Justdial "

please sir can you see in my Image I make red line box in first Image for tite

Comment: I will add in later tonight for you

Comment: please sir How I can extract full title from URL

Comment: I have added it in. Have you run the latest edit above? Bottom version