# Getting data from URL into MS Access table

Tags: html, vba, api, ms-access, url

There's a website that provides weather data:  https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather/weather-data-services

I want to import that data into a table with a button click.  The discussion below seems useful to that, but I am not a strong enough VBA coder to translate this to a functional script.
[Get data from URL using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224011/get-data-from-url-using-excel-vba)

Here's an example of the URL data I would like to move into a table.
https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/garden%20city%2C%20tx?unitGroup=us&elements=datetime%2Ctempmax%2Cprecip%2Cpreciptype%2Cwindgust%2Cwindspeed&include=days&key=KVP7BF7EYTKGZK236GEFF4RGX&contentType=csv

Can anyone help guide me in how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my function `DownloadFile` found on **GitHub** [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl) and this code:

```vb
Public Function LinkData()

    Dim Url         As String
    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim Success     As Long
    
    Url = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/garden%20city%2C%20tx?unitGroup=us&elements=datetime%2Ctempmax%2Cprecip%2Cpreciptype%2Cwindgust%2Cwindspeed&include=days&key=KVP7BF7EYTKGZK236GEFF4RGX&contentType=csv"
    FileName = "C:\Test\WeatherData.csv"
    
    Success = DownloadFile(Url, FileName)
    If Success = 0 Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , "WeatherData", FileName, True
    End If

End Function
```

Call this from the button click:

```vb
Private Sub YourButton_Click()

    LinkData

End Sub
```

That will download and link the file as a table ready to use:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I've been following your answers on this site for years.  Thanks for all you do to help!  I copied your "Internet" module from the GitHub site.  I am a little confused about the execution of the Public Function above.   I'd like to import weather data with a button press.  I am not exactly sure how to execute your function to populate the Access table.

Comment: Simply call the function from the button click - see edited answer, please.

Comment: It will be in folder, you specify, here "C:\Test": `FileName = "C:\Test\WeatherData.csv"`.

Comment: Don't use a OneDrive folder. The displayed name is different from the actual name.

Comment: You are most likely not allowed to save files directly in the system root folder. Why don't you run my tested example _as is_?

Comment: Can't tell. I tried again on this my other workstation, and the code ran right away and linked the file/table.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to have it programmatically open that file once it saves?  Maybe that will help flush out the problem since there is no error message when it doesn't save the file.

Comment: It is not saving as a .csv...  I found it it saving as an "Internet shortcut".  Here is the file path where search found it:  file:///C:/Weather%2520Data.   Although I can search and find it, clicking that file to open gives an error:  Windows cannot find file " ".  Make sure you typed the name correctly, then try again.".   The code tries to save something, but it's not a valid file for me and not a .csv.  And there is no table formed in MS Access.

Comment: Added demo at GitHub. See chat.

Comment: The chat vanished. So: [demo](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl/tree/master/demos).

Comment: When I click the hyperlink of your name, it takes me to your profile but I don't see the option to send a chat.   Perhaps you could initiate it to take this off the board?  When I click "Load Weather" in your demo, I get a message "OK" as if it completed, but only an invalid shortcut is saved.  I would like to troubleshoot this further.   Perhaps the issue is Windows 64 vs 32?

Comment: This a [direct link](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl/raw/master/demos/WeatherData.zip).

Comment: There was no problem accessing the other link to your file.  Your file works great, but has the errors discussed in previous post.

Comment: The only "link" I can't see is how to "chat" with you instead of continuing to post here on this forum.  I would also like to send you a screenshot so you can see what happens on my end when using your file.

Comment: I don't know. I tried again, and `FileName = "C:\Test\WeatherData.csv"` is downloaded from [here](https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/garden%20city%2C%20tx?unitGroup=us&elements=datetime%2Ctempmax%2Cprecip%2Cpreciptype%2Cwindgust%2Cwindspeed&include=days&key=KVP7BF7EYTKGZK236GEFF4RGX&contentType=csv) created in the `C:\Test` folder, and linked nicely as table `Weather` when clicking the button.

Comment: So your code created "C:/Test" folder that didn't exist before you clicked the button?  Did it also create a MS Access table?

Comment: Yes. You can modify the code to use another folder. The table will be an attached table using the downloaded file as source.

Comment: For this version of MS Access 2016 and Windows 10 64-bit, that coding does not do for me what it does for you.  If I had a way to copy/paste screenshots I would show you how some of the code is red and the downloaded file is an "internet shortcut", the file location folder is not created, and no table is created in MS Access.

Comment: You can create an "issue" at GitHub.